# When is an irreducible unramified principal series representation $K$-spherical?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups, p-adic-groups

Let $G = \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb Q_p)$, $T$ the usual maximal torus of $G$, and $K = \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb Z_p)$.

Let $\chi$ be an unramified character of $T$, with $\chi(t_1, ... , t_n) = |t_1|^{s_1} \cdots |t_n|^{s_n}$ for $s_i \in \mathbb C$, uniquely determined up to an integer multiple of $\frac{2\pi i}{\log p}$.  Let $I_{\chi} = \operatorname{Ind}_{TU}^G \chi$ be the unramified principal series representation of $\chi$.

Assume that $\chi$ is regular, i.e. $s_i \equiv s_j$ only for $i = j$.  By a theorem of Casselman, $I_{\chi}$ is irreducible if and only if $s_i \not\equiv s_j \pm 1$ for all $i$ and $j$.

Every smooth irreducible $K$-spherical representation of $G$ is known to be a subrepresentation of an unramified principal series representation.  Is there a known description of which characters $\chi$ for which $I_{\chi}$ admits a $K$-spherical irreducible subrepresentation?  Is there a known description of which characters $\chi$ for which $I_{\chi}$ is irreducible and $K$-spherical?

Comment: In fact, Casselman determines characters such that the spherical vector generates the repn, and so that the spherical vector generates the dual. These two criteria then combine to give the irreducibility criterion. That is, there is more information in Casselman's result than just the irreducibility. Is this the kind of thing you're wanting?